# POST Request Not Recognizing Headers

Tags: javascript, post, aws-lambda, http-post, axios

I am trying to make a **POST** request to an AWS Lambda Python Script I have set up.

I have already heard about solving the issue of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` by adding a header to the Response from AWS lambda, that looks like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`, and I implemented this in the code I was working on for the get request. Then when I begun creating a **POST** request, I did the same thing, so that the new **POST** request originally looked like this:

```
def post(event, context):
    try:
        return dict(
            statusCode=200,
            headers= {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"},
            body="test"
        )
    except Exception as ex:
        return dict(
            statusCode=500,
            body=str(ex)
        )
```

And this works, in Chrome's Network-Tab I see that we pass a post request and there is no issue, and the header is recognized properly, allowing Cross-Origin calls. But this is pretty much just the **GET** request I have which is already set up and working. So when I update it to be more similar to a **POST METHOD** and do what I want the problems begin.

So my code, that I want to be performed in the **POST** request is simple, I should be able to make the request like such,

```
def post(event, context):
    try:
        result=str(event.get("inputOne") + event.get("inputTwo"))
        return dict(
            statusCode=200,
            headers= {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"},
            body=result
        )
    except Exception as ex:
        return dict(
            statusCode=500,
            body=str(ex)
        )
```

When I test this in the AWS Lambda Management console, my code works, and I get the expected response back in the body.

But then when I try and call the **POST** endpoint from my React Site, I once again am getting the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'THE_POST_URL' from origin     
'http://localhost:XXX' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-   
Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

So for some reason, when the body variable is not just a simple string in quotes like "this" <- it fails. I believe this has to do with the Content-Type in the request being of the form *application/json;charset=UTF-8* while my request only accepts (as it says in dev-tools) *application/json* however even when trying to add the headers to accept this format for content-type, I am still getting the same issues.

I am not entirely sure why the header worked on the **GET** request, but not the **POST** request, and would appreciate anyone being able to help teach me, thank you!

EDIT: I have also tried adding `'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': "OPTIONS,GET,POST"` to the headers of the post response, but this did not work either.

Comment: `I believe this has to do with the Content-Type in the request being of the form application/json;charset=UTF-8` - yes, with that header the browser will make an `OPTIONS` preflight request, I'm surprised you're not seeing this in your browser console - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests for information about this OPTIONS preflight

Comment: Yeah, I am not seeing anything about `OPTIONS` in the console. I had a read through of that link you gave me, so from my understanding do I have to add something like `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` to the header?

Comment: @JaromandaX — The error message says "requested resource" not "preflight request"

Comment: @Quentin - as I said in my comment, *I'm surprised you're not seeing this in your browser console*, because having content-type of application/json should trigger a CORS preflight

Comment: @JaromandaX — Which suggests the preflight is passing and the actual request is failing.

Comment: @Quentin - Do you have any idea why the headers of the `POST` would not be recognized? The Headers set up in the `GET` request the same way are recognized allowing `CORS` to pass, but judging by the error, in this request the header is not even being acknowledged.

Comment: @ZacharyFerretti — No. You haven't provided a [mcve]. I don't know how the JS is set up to make the request. I don't know how the AWS is set up to process the response. I don't know how any intermediary services (like API Gateway) are configured to add CORS.

Comment: @Quentin - I will look into that today, and setting up API-Gateway as right now I do not have an API-Gateway service set up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Quentin as you had made me think of, there were problems with the way I had set up my lambda and the API integration. Feel free to look at the answer to see how I solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading through the comments on my question, I decided it was worth going and taking a harder look at the way I had my API Gateway, and Lambda service set up on AWS.

I began using the `curl` utility in order to try and test my post-call from a terminal utility and found that there it was also failing, but I was able to use CloudWatch to debug, the issue and finally get it working.

The problem that I was facing with my curl Request was that I was not properly formatting the JSON input, but even when I was the Lambda was transforming the event improperly, not resulting in a Dict, as expected.

The curl call I was using can be seen:

```
curl -X POST  https://myURL.execute-api.myREGION.amazonaws.com/stage/yourPOST \
-d '{"inputOne":80000,"inputTwo":85}'
```

But in order to read that input properly, and then work with it, I had to update my code in the Lambda to reflect parsing the input properly, this updated lambda code can be found here. The `event` object that you are passing to this lambda is a `DICT` object, so on the first line, we use `JSON.loads` to decode the "body" value of the event, into a dict that we store as `body`. Then to get the value of the two attributes, we use the command `body.get("yourKey")`.

```
def yourPOST(event, context):

    body=json.loads(event["body"])
    a=body.get("inputOne")
    c=body.get("inputTwo")
```

After making these changes the call from my React site works without error! If anyone has any questions feel free to comment, I hope this helped!

Comment: You save my life!

Comment: Just add some detail. To make the json to string in javascript just use `JSON.stringify(the_json_format_data)`. On the other hand, to prevent CORS issue, I also add  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html.